# Doubles in list

Tags: python

I had a test today and one of the questions asked:
Write function doubles() that takes as input a list of integers and outputs the integers in the list that are exactly twice the previous integer in the list, one per line.

I couldn't figure out how exactly to do this my code was

```
def doubles(x):
    for a in range(len(x)-1):
        for b in (range(a,len(x))):
            if x[a]*2==x[b]:
                print(b)
```

For example doubles([3,0,1,2,3,6,2,4,5,6,5]) would print 2 , 6 , 4

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: What was the problem with your code?

Comment: It wasn't printing out the correct values

Comment: What values was it giving?

Comment: @JGrazza You've asked 8 questions, accepted no answers, and never voted. Time for a trip to the [faq] to learn more about how you are expected to contribute to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is that it compares each value with all values that appear later in the list. But the question asks you to consider adjacent pairs only.

So, you only need to walk the list once. Like this:

```
def doubles(x):
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        if x[i] == 2*x[i-1]:
            print x[i]
```

What's more, your code printed indices rather than values, a fault that I fixed in the above.

Comment: Ohh I see now. I feel stupid for not knowing this but thanks for your help!

Comment: @JGrazza, since David was the first to nail down the root of you problem, printing the index instead of the value at the index, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) his answer.

Comment: @johnthexiii I'd have said that root cause was the double loop and the erroneous comparisons. Also, first should not be chosen over best. The best answer is always the one I would like to see accepted. It shouldn't be down to who can type the fastest, but who can write the best.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to go over the list once, testing each element with the one after it or the one before it.

The example below tests each number with the one after it and stops at the number before last.

```
def doubles(x):
    for i,a in enumerate(x[:-1]):
        if x[i+1] == a*2:
            print a*2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def doubles(lst):
    prev = None
    for actual in lst:
        if prev is not None and actual == 2*prev:
            print actual
        prev = actual
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite simply:

```
def doubles(seq):
    after = seq[1:]
    for previous, current in zip(seq, after):
        if current == previous * 2:
            print(current)
```

Which works as expected:

```
>>> print(list(doubles([3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5])))
2
6 
4
```

We take a slice of the list to get a list of the values from the second one. We then use `zip()` to loop through each value with the previous one, and simply perform the check, and print the value if it matches.

You could also construct this as a generator by replacing `print()` with `yield` (which is generally a better option), or if you really wanted a list:

```
def doubles(seq):
    after = seq[1:]
    return [current for previous, current in zip(seq, after) 
            if current == previous * 2]
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Wow, assumption on my part, simple to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to zip with one element shift and check the element pair for your condition

```
>>> def doubles(x):
    return [b for a,b in zip(x,x[1:]) if b == 2*a]

>>> for e in doubles([3,0,1,2,3,6,2,4,5,6,5]):
    print e


2
6
4
```

Similar solution but just using iterators

```
>>> def doubles(x):
    it1, it2 = tee(x)
    next(it2)
    return [b for a,b in izip(it1,it2) if b == 2*a]

>>> for e in doubles([3,0,1,2,3,6,2,4,5,6,5]):
    print e


2
6
4
```

Comment: By what metric is this the simplest?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops. For each element, you only need to test it against the element preceding it.